# Could not resolve <mx:LinkButton> to a component implementation in Flex Mobile project

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I just created a Flex Mobile project and I received this error when using an mx:LinkButton:

```
Could not resolve <mx:LinkButton> to a component implementation.
```

Here is my Application:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">


    <mx:LinkButton id="contactButton" label="Contact" />
```

Actually, none of the mx components are working? This is not good.

I'm using Flex 4.5.1A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to manually add the mx.swc to the project (even though some mx components are included by default in Flex 4.5+).

Anyway, open your project properties window and go to the build path view. Click Add SWC and browse to:

```
[Flex Framework directory]\frameworks\libs\mx\mx.swc
```

However, you may still get 100's of these errors:

```
Definition mx.skins.spark:AccordionHeaderSkin could not be found.
```

In which case you need to add the source to the skins as described [here](http://killerspaz.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/using-mx-components-on-flexair-mobile/). Click Add Source and browse to:

```
\frameworks\projects\mx\src
```

You may also need to add additional skins. Click Add Source and browse to:

```
/frameworks/projects/sparkskins/src
```